# What does "similar via the <insert matrix here>" mean?

Tags: linear-algebra, terminology

If "$A$ is similar to $B$ via the matrix $P$, are we saying that, $P^{-1} A P = B $?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. It may also mean that $PAP^{-1}=B$. If one only wants to stress that $A$ and $B$ are similar, it doesn't matter whether $P^{-1}AP=B$ or $PAP^{-1}=B$. However, if $P$ is used in actual calculations, you should try to figure out which one the author really means.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. The matrix $P$ may also be termed as similarity transformation. The property is termed as conjugacy in group theory.